# Find the matrix representation of $L$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L:P_3 \rightarrow P_2,L(p(x))=\text{p}'(x)+\text{p}(0).$

Find the matrix representation of L with respect to the bases $E=\{x^2,x,1\}$ and $F=\{2,1-x\}$.

$L(x^2)=2x+0 \\L(x)=1\\L(1)=0+1 \\L(2)=0\\L(1-x)=0-1=-1
$

One must next construct a matrix.

$$A= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\        \end{bmatrix} B= \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0  \\        \end{bmatrix}
$$

However the book solution has this as the answer.

$$A_L=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        -2 & 0 & 0 \\        \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I fix my answer so that I may be able to get the correct answer?

Comment: Are you sure the element in first row and third column is $1/2?$

Comment: You need to send vectors from B to L and their images you need to make as linear combination of vectors from F. Coordinates of that linear combination are columns of matrix $\ A_L$

Comment: @Itay4 It is according to the solutions.

Comment: @Itay4 It is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to check how $L$ "acts" on the elements of $E$ and then represent them with respect to $F$:

$L(x^2)=2x=1 \cdot 2+ (-2)\cdot (1-x)$

$L(x)=1=1/2 \cdot 2+ 0\cdot (1-x)$

$L(1)=1=1/2 \cdot 2+ 0\cdot (1-x)$

Placing the coordinates in columns of matrix gives us the desired result.

Comment: I get that one must get the first derivative then substitute 0 for $x^2$, yet where does $1*2+(-2)(1-x)$ come from if I may ask.

Comment: @Jon You need to represent $2x$ as a linear combination of the polynomials in $F$. Solve the equation: $2x=a\cdot 2 + b \cdot (1-x)$

Comment: So $a=1 \text{ and } b=-2$

Comment: @Jon Exactly...

Comment: Where in your solution did you derive these values?

Comment: @Jon Well, it was just easy to see. But solving an equation like you just did is the way to do it.

Comment: @Jon Because the second and third equations are $1=a \cdot 2 + b \cdot (1-x)$

Comment: Okay I think I see how you did this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your notation is a little misleading since $P_3$ is the vector space for polynomials up to 3rd degree.

So your problem should be written like this

Let  $ \, L $: $P_2 \to P_1$ with bases $E = \{ x^2, x, 1\}$ and $ \, F = \{2, 1 - x\} $.

$\text{Then, } \\ L(x^2) = 2x + 0 = 2x \\  L(x) = 1 + 0 = 1 \\ L(1) = 0 + 1 = 1 $

Putting these results into a matrix using the basis $F$ we get,
$$ A = \pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 1 \cr
-2 & 0 & 0 } $$

Then augmenting the basis $F$ with this matrix we get,

$$
\left( \matrix{  2 & \; 1 \cr 0 & -1} \right| \left. \matrix{ \; 0 & 1 & 1 \cr
   -2 & 0 & 0 } \right)
$$

All that you need to do from here is to $RREF$ this new augmented matrix to get the matrix representation of $L$ with $F$ basis. The resulting matrix will be

$$ 
A_L = \pmatrix{1 & \frac 12 & \frac 12 \cr
-2 & 0 & 0}
$$